# Call external SOAP service with digest authentication in the header

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

From my ESB Proxy service, I have to call an external SOAP webservice needing a Digest authentication  , basically it would be in the Header :

```
<wsse:Security>
         <wsse:UsernameToken>
            <wsse:Username></wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce></wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created></wsu:Created>
         </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>
```

Password must be SHA1 encoded and nonce base64encoded.
How to construct this header inside my Proxy ?

Tks
Nick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood, what you are looking for is to invoke secured service fronted by unsecured proxy.

[This blog](http://ssagara.blogspot.com/2013/07/wso2-esb-set-ws-security-ut-user-names.html) by Sagara nicely explains how to do it(in section 2) and further explains practical problems and answers.

HTH,

DarRay